# Batch- If statement not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

My code is this:

```
set /p input = "Enter the number here: "

if %input%==1 goto New
if %input%==2 goto Load
if %input%==3 exit
```

The program crashes whenever you try to input one of the numbers. It says "was expected at this time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have a parameter `%input%`. But you have a parameter named `%input<space>%`

Write your `set` command without spaces:

```
set variable=value
```

for example:

```
set /p "input=Enter  the number here: "
```